# how to create windows application with mvc

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller

i want to know what is best method is it better to use composite UI application block to help create windows application in mvc or i should go for MVP to create windows application. which is the best method. please if someone could send me urls related to my issue so that i can get a better understanding